# How to get a top object (Window or Page) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Within my custom WPF control I want to get a containing Window or Page. Window.GetWindow() method works fine when control is in a windowed app but when it's in the XBAP app in a browser it returns browser window instead of the page.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 90):

This works for me:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Comment: Great thanks. Missing the Page.GetPage method ... :S

Comment: Very useful! I now can access the controls of the parent window "MyWindow" like this: [ MyWindow mw = parentWindow as MyWindow; ].

Answer (score 30):

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
while (!(parent is Page))
{
    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
}
(parent as Page).DoStuff();
```

Comment: Hi Tomislav Markovski, your solution is very helpful for finding the topmost parent i.e. Page. But the DoStuff() method could not be called. I get error saying 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page' does not contain a definition for 'DoStuff' (are you missing a using directive or an assemply reference?)

I desperately need to call a method in MainPage from a dynamic user control and unable to do this. Help please.

Comment: Change `while (!(parent is Page))` and `(parent as Page).DoStuff();` to test and cast to your page class. If that is MainPage, then `parent is MainPage` etc. Obviously `DoStuff()` should be the name of your function.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the VisualTreeHelper class to retrieve the top-level control :

```
DependencyObject GetTopLevelControl(DependencyObject control)
{
    DependencyObject tmp = control;
    DependencyObject parent = null;
    while((tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tmp)) != null)
    {
        parent = tmp;
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I think I've already posted this comment... This doesn't work when your control is in a Template. The loop ends when you reach the template "root".

Answer (score 0):

i think best way is

```
var obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)Content);
```

Comment: This will only give you the direct parent. Consider if you have multiple nested user controls in one window.