# How to get WPF UserControl's Parent Page in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a `uCtrl` of type `UserControl` in a `parentPg` of type `Page` (instead of a `Window`). And I want to access that `parentPg` in `uCtrl` class so that I can bind some `uCtrl`'s property to `parentPg`'s `Control`.

Like as we get in case of `Window`.

```
public partial class uCtrl : UserControl
{
    Window parentWin;

    public uCtrl()
    {
        parentWin = Window.GetWindow(this);
    }

    public bool IsPrptReady
    {
        get
        {
            //accesing parent Window's control

            if (((pWin)(parentWin)).txt.Text != "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

In above code snippet, I am getting parent `Window` (i.e. of type `pWin`) in `uCtrl` of type `UserControl` and then sets its `Property` (i.e `IsPrptReady`) based on parents Window's `Control` i.e. `txt` of type 'TextBox'.

I want to do the same thing, but in case of `Page` not `Window`.
I have seen a lot of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838825/how-to-get-a-top-object-window-or-page-in-wpf) but nothing solves my problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

The XAML code is as below.

```
<Page x:Class="Stego.Pages.EnDeCoding"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
      xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
      >
      <Grid>
           <userControls:uCtrl x:Name="uCtrlName"/>
      </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463149/628821) in the question you linked to provides the answer you need; specifically the use of the VisualTreeHelper.

Alternatively, you could add a [dependency] property to the user control of type Page and bind the property to the page instance the control is hosted within. Something like:

```
<Page x:Name="page">
  <local:UCtrl Page="{Binding ElementName=page}"/>
</Page>
```

Comment: i have seen that answer and not found my solution. @ibebbs Can you please share a piece of code C# as per my requirement?