# How to get the Window hosting a UIElement instance

Tags: window, c++-winrt, winui-3, visual-tree, dependencyobject

I'm trying to get the `Window` instance which is hosting a [`UIElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) instance in WinUI 3.

There's a [helper method in the Window class in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.getwindow?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-uwp-10.0) ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838825/how-to-get-a-top-object-window-or-page-in-wpf)) but i cannot find something similar for C++/WinRT.

I tried [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=winrt-22621) as some suggested but it doesn't help here; none of the parents were of type [`winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1).

Is it possible to get the hosting `Window` of a dependency object?

Comment: Do you actually need the `Window` instance, or are you fine with a plain old `HWND` as well?

Comment: @IInspectable I need the actual instance so that i can cast to its projection or implementation type.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a UWP application, each UI thread already has a Window that can be retrieved using the static [Window.Current property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.current?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-xaml-window-current).

If it is a C++/WinRT WinUI3 in Desktop application, Window implements `IWindowNative` to enable interop through the **Window's HWND (WindowHandle)**. You could get the **handle** of the Window and do what you want. Like:

```
 // Get the current window's HWND by passing in the Window object
     var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

For more information, please check: [Window Class-Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1)

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++-winrt]. The code here isn't C++.

Comment: I guess [`Window.Current()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.current?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) might be an alternative but MS writes _Desktop apps always return null_.

Comment: @ridilculous Yes, but your app is not a UWP application, right? As I mentioned, if you are not a UWP application, you could only get the handle of the window.

Comment: I need the actual instance so that i can cast to its projection or implementation type. Or is there a way to get the instance afterwards using the `HWND`?

Comment: @ridilculous hello, did you find an alternative?

Comment: @Jacques no generic one; luckily i could store it explicitly somewhere and just get it from there but it's not a nice solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'd be glad to see it, I can't find any solution at all.

Comment: I just get `InvalidCastException` when I call `WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this)` in this case `this` is my Page.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has long puzzled me. And I find this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.hosting.elementcompositionpreview.getappwindowcontent) available since winrt-18362.
Unfortunately, the AppWindow needed here is under namespace Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting rather than Microsoft.UI.Windowing. The later one is easy to get from a HWND.
BTW, I've also tried to store the Window instance somewhere but always failed with some error related to its constructor. Then, I finally achieved it by storing it as a static const reference and reassigning the variable through its pointer.

I just find an [alternative method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/winui3) to manage Window instances here. This would help us get window from any known custom implementation type. But there would be link error with no initialization or compile error due to no 'inline'.